# How to play this bishop & pawn endgame?

Tags: analysis, endgame, bishop-endgame

```
[Title "Black to move"]
[StartFlipped "0"]
[fen "6k1/p4p2/1p2pPp1/7p/3Pb2P/1B2P1P1/P7/2K5 b - - 0 33"]
```

I'm Black. In the game I deliberately allowed White pushing the pawn to f6, I was expecting something like `...g5, ...Kh7, ...Kg6` to pick up the pawn. But then I realised after `...g5`, White has Bc2 which forces the exchange of the bishop. Once the bishop is exchanged, white should win with the passed d-pawn after e4 & d5.

**Question**: What's the best continuation for Black here? Can I take advantage of the weak f6 pawn? I don't have a computer with me, so computer analysis is fine. My human evaluation is very danger for Black (thus I'd misevaluated the endgame by allowing it to happen).

Comment: White won't win with the passed d-pawn - you are just in time to stop it, and White's king can't help because of your queenside pawns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If White tries to hinder your plan by exchanging the bishops he loses the pawn endgame. I have provided brief analysis in the below diagram, see the sublines. Then I have tried to play this endgame with both colors versus computer.

Computer chose `1...Kf8` as strongest but with some "only moves" I managed to save the draw. This is illustrated in the below diagram as the main line.

I played your plan with `...g5 + ...Kh7` but computer found good resource in `Be8!`, which secures a draw. You will find my play as Black in the below diagram as a subline.

To conclude: you can not exploit your advantage because White generates enough counterplay thanks to your kingside pawns being on the color of your bishop.

```
[StartFlipped "0"]
[Title "Black to move"]
[fen "6k1/p4p2/1p2pPp1/7p/3Pb2P/1B2P1P1/P7/2K5 b - - 0 33"]

1...Kf8 (1... g5 2. hxg5 Kh7 3. Ba4! (3.Bc2? Bxc2-+ 4.Kxc2 Kg6 5.e4 Kxg5 6.e5 Kf5 7.Kd3 $8 b5 $22 8.a3 a5 9.Ke3 b4 10.axb4 axb4 11.Kd3 b3 $8 12.Kc3 Ke4!-+) 3...Kg6 4. Be8!= $8 Bf3 5. Kd2 Kxg5 6. Bxf7 Kxf6 7. Be8 Kg5 8. Bd7 Bd5 9. a3 Kg4 10. e4! Bxe4 11. Bxe6+ Kxg3 12. d5 h4 13. d6 Bc6 14. d7 Bxd7 15. Bxd7 h3 16. Bxh3 Kxh3=) 2.Ba4! a6 3. Bd7! Kg8 4. Be8! Kf8 5. Bd7 Kg8 6. Be8 Kf8 7. Bd7 Kg8 1/2-1/2
```

Answer (score -1):

Who is on move?  If it is white to move this looks won for white. If it is black you need to get the king on the Qside to hold a draw.

NOTE:  human analysis not done by computer.  It might be wrong but OTB that is what I expect to happen.

Comment: again someone downvotes without saying why.  the bullies who do this are clearly also cowards.